# CUDA device C++ class, in what memory type are object variables stored and is it possible to change it?

Tags: c++, class, memory, cuda, gpgpu

So I am playing around with CUDA C++ programming. I tried to create a class which is run on the device, something like this:

```
class DeviceClass {
    int deviceInt = 5;

    __DEVICE__ void DeviceFunc()
    {
        printf("Value of device var: %d\n", deviceInt);
    }
}
```

Now, unless I missed something in the example this will actually run correctly on the device. I can initialize it using new from a `__global__` method and run the `DeviceFun()` method from there.

In which memory on the device is the variable `deviceInt` stored?

Can I force it to be allocated in another type of memory than the default one? For example I might want to put very large data arrays into global memory and some other stuff more locally in faster memory.

Is it a good idea to do CUDA device class design like this, or will I run into problems later on with larger designs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objects are stored in whatever memory space you specify when they are defined (which is also why it is illegal to use memory space specifications in class or structure definitions).

The object model has some hard limitations on when objects with non-default constructors or with virtual members can be used, but it is possible to explicitly instantiate or statically define objects in `__global__`, `__shared__`, `__constant__` or local/stack memory.

"Modern" (compute capability >= 2.0) GPUs have ABI support, which means that static pointer introspection at compile time also works correctly.

So it would be possible to define a trivial class with an empty constructor like this:

```
struct foo
{
    float x, y;

    __device__ float f() const
    {
        return x*x + y*y;
    };

    __device__ bool operator< (const foo& x) const
    {
        return (f() < x.f());
    };
};
```

and then use it in device code like this:

```
__device__ foo foo_min(const foo& x, const foo& y)
{
    return (x < y) ? x : y;
}

__global__ void kernel(foo *indata, foo *outdata, int N)
{
    int idx = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x  *blockDim.x;
    foo localmin = indata[idx];
    for(; idx < N; idx += blockDim.x * gridDim.x)
    {
        localmin = foo_min(localmin, indata[idx]);
    };

    /* simple shared memory reduction */
    __shared__ foo buff[128];
    buff[threadIdx.x] = localmin;
    __syncthreads();

    if (threadIdx.x < 64) {
        buff[threadIdx.x] = foo_min(buff[threadIdx.x], buff[threadIdx.x+64]);
    }
    __syncthreads();

    if (threadIdx.x < 32) {
        buff[threadIdx.x] = foo_min(buff[threadIdx.x], buff[threadIdx.x+32]);
    }
    __syncthreads();
    if (threadIdx.x < 16) {
        buff[threadIdx.x] = foo_min(buff[threadIdx.x], buff[threadIdx.x+16]);
    }
    __syncthreads();

    if (threadIdx.x < 8) {
        buff[threadIdx.x] = foo_min(buff[threadIdx.x], buff[threadIdx.x+8]);
    }
    __syncthreads();

    if (threadIdx.x < 4) {
        buff[threadIdx.x] = foo_min(buff[threadIdx.x], buff[threadIdx.x+4]);
    }
    __syncthreads();

    if (threadIdx.x < 2) {
        buff[threadIdx.x] = foo_min(buff[threadIdx.x], buff[threadIdx.x+2]);
    }
    __syncthreads();

    if (threadIdx.x == 0) {
        outdata[blockIdx.x] = foo_min(buff[0], buff[1]);
    }
}
```

[warning: this code has never been near a compiler and is not guaranteed to work]

So in the kernel, you have

1. pointers to foo in global memory
2. a static shared memory array of foo objects
3. a thread local foo instance

and it is possible to pass all of them to the device function `foo_min` without needing to do anything special in the code, and the compiler understands and handles the cases transparently.